# MySQL simple trigger can't find the column in another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm new with MySQL. I have this trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `increment`;
TRIGGER `increment` 
AFTER INSERT ON `table1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   UPDATE table2 
   SET table2.mycolumn = table2.mycolumn+1 
   WHERE table2.id = table1.id; 
END
```

It gives error:

> Unknown column 'table1.id'

Why? (The column exists). If I use this the trigger works fine:

> WHERE table2.id = 1;

Help me understand this, please.

Comment: [Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks, I changed the line affected (SET NEW.table2.mycolumn = OLD.table2.mycolumn+1) but it still can't find table1.id and that row isn't affected so I can't use OLD.table1.id or anything. I don't think I understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NEW` or `OLD` to refer to the columns of the row that caused the trigger to be executed. But not columns of a table you subsequently change in a SQL statement in the body of the trigger.

Example:

```
TRIGGER `increment` 
AFTER INSERT ON `table1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   UPDATE table2 
   SET table2.mycolumn = table2.mycolumn+1 
   WHERE table2.id = NEW.id; 
END
```

In this example, `NEW.id` refers to the id column of the current row inserted to the `increment` table.

There is no `OLD` version of the current row in an insert trigger, because it's a new row.

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought I had to find the old equivalent to the new data and was getting a bit confused. I get it now, many thanks!